# convert a simple maven project to a webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, jersey

I created a simple maven project using just jpa persistence as a framework, and now I have to make this same project a webapp using jersey, but I don't know the procedure I'll have to follow !

Comment: What have you searched before raising the question here?

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to update your project you can use

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html

Example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2 -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service -Dpackage=com.example -DarchetypeVersion=2.11
```